# ORA-00907 while trying to create a table with automatic column

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, ora-00907

I'm attempting to create a table with an automatic column, the value of which is computed using a function I've defined. However, when I try to create the table I keep getting ora-00907: Missing right parenthesis. Can anyone help?

Here is the CREATE code:

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_EMP2 (
SSN CHAR(9), 
EMP_NUM2 CHAR(5) automatic as newemp2id(SSN), 
Fname VARCHAR2(15), 
Lname VARCHAR2(15), 
Bdate DATE
)
```

Here is the code for the function **newemp2id**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION newemp2id (i_ssn NCHAR) RETURN NCHAR
IS
BEGIN
RETURN 'E'||(1000+SUBSTR(i_ssn,6,4));
END
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

UPDATE: I'm using Oracle Express Edition on a Windows Vista machine, in case that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hadn't heard of the syntax prior to this, but all I could find is [this PDF for Oracle RDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/rdb/automatic-columns-132042.pdf).  [RDB was/is a separate product for Oracle databases](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/rdb/overview/index.html)... [Confirmed - not supported on 10g](http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm#i2095331)

Use a [BEFORE INSERT trigger](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_triggers.htm) instead, because I don't believe the syntax you're using is valid for Oracle Express (10g effectively) - there's no mention in the [CREATE TABLE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_7002.htm) or [ALTER TABLE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_3001.htm#i2103924) documentation.

I'm not fond of using triggers, I'd prefer to have a single stored procedure for inserting into given table(s) & only allow anyone to use the procedure rather than direct table access...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER newemp2_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT
    ON new_mep2
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    -- Update created_by field to the username of the person performing the INSERT
    :new.emp_num2 := newemp2id(new.ssn)
END;
```

Though frankly, this is overcomplicated when it could be handled in a view:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_emp AS
  SELECT t.ssn,
         'E'||(1000+SUBSTR(i_ssn,6,4)) AS emp_num2
    FROM NEW_EMP2 t
```

Comment: That's the nice thing about virtual columns - they'll save on creating unnecessary views and denormalised data. I think it is even possible to put constraints on them. One day we'll get Oracle 11!

Answer (score 1):

What's an automatic column supposed to be? Did you mean a purely computed i.e. virtual column? Then your statement should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_EMP2 (
SSN CHAR(9), 
EMP_NUM2 CHAR(5) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( newemp2id(SSN) ) VIRTUAL, 
Fname VARCHAR2(15), 
Lname VARCHAR2(15), 
Bdate DATE
)
```

And your functions need to declared deterministic:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION newemp2id (i_ssn NCHAR) RETURN NCHAR DETERMINISTIC 
IS
BEGIN
RETURN 'E'||(1000+SUBSTR(i_ssn,6,4));
END
```

If I'm not mistaken, virtual columns were introduced with Oracle 11g.

Comment: According to this document (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/rdb/automatic-columns-132042.pdf) Oracle has supported computed and automatic columns since v7.1. I'm new to Oracle, so if the product being described in the article is different, then clearly that's my issue...

Comment: @Brian Driscoll: Oracle RDB is for OpenVMS only - it's not the Oracle RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Express is Oracle 10g.

According to the manual (http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm#i2095331) there is no "automatic" keyword and Oracle 10 has never supported "computed columns"

Oracle 11g supports virtual columns, but they are created using `GENERATED ALWAYS`, not even Oracle 11g has an `automatic` keyword

Why do you think this should work in Oracle?